# How to download a page in java and save it to UTF-8?

Tags: java, utf-8, httpurlconnection

**This function sends a request to server in UTF8 and receives in UTF8:**

```
public String downloadPage(String _url, String _reqm, String _params) {
        try {
            if (_reqm == null || (_reqm == "POST" && _params == null))
                throw new IOException();

            URL _myURL = null;

            if (_reqm == "GET") {
                _myURL = new URL(_params == null ? _url : _url + "?" + _params); //URLEncoder.encode(_params, "UTF-8")
            } else if (_reqm == "POST") {
                _myURL = new URL(_url);
            }

            HttpURLConnection pageConnection = (HttpURLConnection) _myURL.openConnection();
            pageConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            pageConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            pageConnection.setDoInput(true);
            pageConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            pageConnection.setRequestMethod(_reqm);

            pageConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
            pageConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            pageConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
            pageConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            pageConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31");

            if (_reqm == "POST") {
                pageConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(pageConnection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(_params); //URLEncoder.encode(_params, "UTF-8")
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pageConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(inputLine + "\n");
            }

            reader.close();
            return text.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
```

**This function saves an UTF8 string to a file in UTF8:**

```
public void writeFile(String _content, String _fileName) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(_fileName)), "UTF-8"));
            out.write(_content);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I use the two, like this:

```
String downloadedPage = myTelecom.downloadPage("http://www.sbrf.ru/moscow/ru/", "GET", null);
myIO.writeFile(downloadedPage, "original.html");
```

Despite the multiple indication of encoding, I could not make it work.
Regardless of the request method or domain or "Accept-Charset" or "charset", it does not work.

No russian, no hungarian characters look like they supposed to look like, and I do not know where I made a mistake.

What could be the problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The server is sending data in Windows-1251. And you are not explicitly passing any encoding to InputStreamReader, causing it to use platform default encoding for decoding, which can only by accident be Windows-1251.